# Remove attr javascript

Tags: javascript, css

**Resumen**
Tengo una etiqueta SVG que la creo con js asi la creo

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(465,260)")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", "M-30.5,0L0,20.5L0,-20.5Z")
  .style({
    "fill": "white",

  });
```

Necesito agregarle una clase y lo hago de esta manera

```
svg.attr("class", "quit");
```

Mi problema esta en quitarle esa misma clase a la misma etiqueta, ya intente con la funcion de **removeAttr** y **removeClass** y no he podido, me pueden ayudar ?

Comment: ¿[Buscaste en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)?

Comment: Sip, y tampoco funciono

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún error en consola al hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar esta función, donde myStyle sea tu clase a eliminar:

```
element.classList.remove("myStyle");
```